# Omniauth + facebook not working as expected

Tags: facebook, sinatra, omniauth

I am new to Omniauth. I am making a toy application. It displays a random sentence and that's all. I am using Sinatra + Omniauth. I would like to make it a Facebook application.
 I basically followed this tutorial:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook
(current app at: http://frasesbarrio.heroku.com/ )

I have pointed the fb app to http://frasesbarrio.heroku.com/

I have this code:

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, APP_ID, APP_SECRET, { :scope => 'status_update, publish_stream, offline_access' }
end


get '/auth/facebook/callback' do
#  raise "auth facebook"
  session['fb_auth'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  session['fb_token'] = session['fb_auth']['credentials']['token']
  session['fb_error'] = nil

  redirect '/'
end
```

And I have several problems:

When an user request the FB app, Facebook issues a POST on my /
I think this is weird because I have not seen anything similar in any tutorial. 
I have just :

```
post '/' do  

  redirect "http://localhost:4567/auth/facebook"

  get_sentence  
  @ranking = get_ranking
  erb :index
end
```

Doing so, the user will be redirected to application on canvas facebook page with a big facebook sign, if the user clicks on it the authentification continues and he is redirected to /.

I mean redirected completely, outside the facebook canvas and domain.

I have seen several tutorials and everyone is doing the same than me, so I really don't know what can be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook implements your application as an iFrame inside the canvas. The default behavior for Facebook is to request the canvas by making a POST request. This behavior is documented in the following article:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/canvas/post/

You can turn off this behavior in the advanced settings of your application by disabling "POST for Canvas".